# dissabling touchpad buttons on a laptop

Tags: touchpad

Does anyone knows how to disable the left click button on a laptop touchpad? It stays pressed all the time, and I'll like to disable it and use the right click as a left click. Does anyone knows if that is possible?

Or at least to disable both of them.

Thank you

Comment: What make & model laptop do you have?

Comment: @Kez: i have a Acer TravelMate 5730

Answer (score 1):

your newest driver come with an utility to let you remap your touchpad keys, check it out

Answer (score 0):

its system dependant - you could probably disable the whole device from control panel (device manager is a good bet, or mouse settings), and use an external pointing device?

Answer (score 0):

Disable it from hardware profile, then use a usb mouse